Who is the owner of a gifted token? Can Coveted Falcon steal gifts?
If I play a Bloomburrow card that gifts my opponent a permanent, such as Blooming Blast, who is the owner of that permanent?  Coveted Falcon can steal back permanents a player owns but doesn't control, so I'm curious if it can steal back gifts.

Your opponent will be the owner of that token.
When you gift your opponent a token, they create that token. That means they will be the owner of that token.

111.2. The player who creates a token is its owner. The token enters the battlefield under that player’s control.


702.174d “Gift a Food” means the effect is “The chosen player creates a Food token.”
702.174f “Gift a tapped Fish” means the effect is “The chosen player creates a tapped 1/1 blue Fish creature token.”
702.174h “Gift a Treasure” means the effect is “The chosen player creates a Treasure token.”
702.174i “Gift an Octopus” means the effect is “The chosen player creates an 8/8 blue Octopus creature token.”

That means you cannot steal them with Coveted Falcon.
